# Treat tabs in Ruby as two spaces, not four

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, markdown

In [How do you handle parameters & blocks when dynamically defining a method in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512506/how-do-you-handle-parameters-blocks-when-dynamically-defining-a-method-in-ruby) , code is being indented four spaces rather than the idiomatic two spaces, because the OP is using tabs.

If markdown treated tabs as being two spaces rather than four, then it would look idiomatic.

I assume this could be handled either based on markdown's automatic detection of programming lanuage, or the tags used.

If someone really likes four spaces per indentation level, then they can do so by manually using four spaces.

Comment: Based on past experience, if you want a change made to the code formatter, you're probably going to be told to file a bug with Google Code Prettify instead of MSO, since that's the engine the team uses.

Comment: @PopularDemand: Detabbing is Markdown, though, not Prettify (actually, it's pretty much a Markdown preprocessing step).

Comment: Then I'm glad I left a "based on past experience" comment and not a real answer, @balpha. Thanks for the clarification. Is Prettify purely deciding which colors to assign to what text, then?

Comment: Yep; Prettify only ever sees the code after its has been converted from Markdown to HTML and added to the DOM as a `<pre><code>` block. All it then does is make it shine in pretty colors. @pop

Answer (score 14):

1. If there's one thing that you can call "majority agreement" in the whole tab-vs-spaces war, it's that one tab, when converted to spaces, equals four spaces. Second place being eight.
2. I am not a Ruby programmer, but a quick web search suggests that by far not all people agree on the 2-spaces indentation.
3. Would you also have to indent your code blocks by two tabs then for them to show up as code in Markdown?

But first and formost:

## If they wanted to have "idiomatic" Ruby code, wouldn't they use two spaces instead of tabs?

Comment: More experienced users generally use two spaces, but newbies don't.

Comment: @Andrew so you want to make it harder on newbies of every *other* language?

Comment: Ruby code which is tab-indented **is not idomatic**. There is no point in making it *look* idomatic, the whole point is to avoid tabs for *exactly* this reason.

Comment: @BobCratchit: I mentioned in the proposal that it'd only be for Ruby code, and discussed ways to have it only be done on Ruby code.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Ah sorry I missed that subtlety.