# Improving the post/question editor for coding support?

Tags: feature-request, editor

I *love* StackExchange. The only frustration is copying and pasting code over or writing code in answers and posts. For example, to write the following block of Python:

```
1. def hello(self):
2.     if (self.DEBUG == True):
3.         print "Hello World!"
```

For line 1, I had to type <kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>.
For line 2, I had to type <kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>.
For line 3, I had to type <kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>.

It'd be awesome if there'd be a way to enable <kbd>Tab</kbd> on an opt in basis for indenting code.

Comment: It's even more annoying when you're trying to do multi level indentation and Ctrl-K kills the existing indentation rather than adding more.

Comment: What is this Ctrl+K of which you speak?

Comment: Shortcut for code markup - the same a clicking the {} button on the toolbar.

Comment: And the beauty is that *this is so easy*.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't there be some sort of accessibility concerns if you started capturing <kbd>Tab</kbd> in the editor? Keyboard nav would be broken. I suppose that's why it has to be opt-in.

I'm definitely for this. To go one step further, you could build in a keyboard shortcut to autoindent the selected text. That way you might not even need to worry about <kbd>Tab</kbd>, but people could still easily indent their code. It'd even create a quick cleanup procedure for things like new user/low quality posts: edit, autoindent, save.

Comment: Opt-in is _exactly_ for the reasons you describe. For those of us who don't need accessibility at the moment and want to tweak things to make input a lot faster, this would be great.

Comment: And yes, autoindent would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

I would be wary of capturing <kbd>Tab</kbd> in the editor only because not everyone will necessarily agree on the same number of spaces per tab (for instance, [should Ruby code treat tabs as two spaces or four?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116055/162705)).

Likewise, although I would personally love to have an autoindent feature, the same caveat with respect to the number of spaces per tab still applies.

Comment: Well, for SE's implementation of Markdown at least, a tab is four spaces. [Just sayin'](http://memegenerator.net/cache/instances/400x/11/12140/12431759.jpg).

Comment: @TKKocheran Ah, true enough.

Comment: Also, they should flat out swap out the editor for vim, but that's for another feature request.